# Criar um método para Substituir Caracteres numa String

Tags: java

Alguém me pode ajudar a criar um método que substitua os Caracteres de uma String? Por exemplo,

```
String nova = antiga.replace('a','1');
```

Isto apenas substitui uma letra.

Eu queria criar um método para todas as outras letras do alfabeto que pudesse usar sempre que eu desejasse substituir os caracteres de determinada String.

Comment: Você ta usando entrada de dados através do console ? Ou tem alguma telinha visual ?

Comment: @Matheus como assim telinha visual?

Comment: Saber se é uma interface grafica ou console é irrelevante pra duvida, o `replaceall` mencionado abaixo faz exatamente isso que você quer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O próprio método [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) tem esta finalidade. Observe que existe uma sobrecarga que recebe dois `CharSequence`'s como parâmetro.

Ou seja, você consegue fazer assim

```
String nova = antiga.replace("alguma coisa", "outra coisa");
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/KUna)